# Changing .scnp in GitHub pod doesn't take the effects on run

Tags: xcode, scenekit

Hi I'm using the pod https://github.com/roytornado/RSLoadingView
I changed Twins.scnp effects and added image to the animation, but the changes doesn't have effect when I run the app.

```
let loadingView = RSLoadingView(effectType: .twins)
loadingView.show(on: tabBarController!.view)
```

It appears with this code over the screen, but it's still original version of it.

Answer (score 1):

This framework does not support custom .sncp files from what I can tell. But I'll try to answer anyways.

I'm assuming you're loading the example project for the pod, but my answer applies if you're installing it it to your project as well.

Changing the `Twins.scnp` wouldn't change the effect because the example has the pod which is built and loaded already as a framework. The `Twins.scnp` file is embedded in the framework, you just changed the source file that builds the pod. You'd have to rebuild the pod and install that new built pod into the example app to see your changes. This approach is likely too cumbersome for your needs.

You generally shouldn't change source files for the framework unless you're planning on forking and rebuilding, or you're working on the framework with the author.

If you really want to change the source of the framework and rebuild it with your changes you can do this:

1. Fork the project, pull your forked version to your computer
2. Adjust the .sncp files to your liking
3. git commit/push your changes to your forked repo, make sure to push to the master branch
4. install the pod in the project you'd like to see this in with this line:

`pod 'RSLoadingView', :git => 'https://github.com/yourUsername/RSLoadingView.git', :branch => 'master'`

replace `yourUsername` based on what you see in GitHub for the url of your forked repo.

If you do all this you'll see the changes, but this approach is generally not a sustainable solution. You wouldn't get updates from the original author and you're essentially making your own version of the pod.